# Unable to edit multiple paperclip images in 1 form with Rails 4

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, strong-parameters

I'm trying to upload multiple images with paperclip through 1 form, but I'm getting a Unpermitted parameters error.

This is my code:

Model:

```
class Recentjacket < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :jacketimage, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"}, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

end
```

Controller:

```
def recent
  @recentjacket = Recentjacket.all
end

def update
  params['recentjacket'].keys.each do |id|
  @jacket = Recentjacket.find(id)

  @jacket.update_attributes(recentjacket_params)
  end

  redirect_to '/recent'
end

private
  def recentjacket_params
    params.require(:recentjacket).permit(:jacketimage)
  end
```

Html.slim

```
= form_for recent_path, html: { multipart: true } do |k| 
  - @recentjacket.each do |j|
    = fields_for "recentjacket[]", j do |jacketfields|
      = jacketfields.file_field :jacketimage

    = k.submit "Update"
```

So basically there are 12 recentjackets in the database and when something is changed, it should overwrite the image.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem:

```
  def update
    if params.has_key?(:jacket)
      Recentjacket.update(params[:jacket].keys, params[:jacket].values)
      redirect_to '/recent'
    else
      redirect_to '/recent/edit',
        notice: 'No Files were selected to upload!' 
    end
  end
```